# Applying site theme in REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, theme

I have 300 site collections i need to change the theme on. 
I know you do this by cog -> change look -> theme and then you choose the theme you require. I have seen /_api/thememanager/ApplyTheme API but I cannot seem to get this to work and also i do not want to send off each theme settings, the theme is already there and out of the box. any idea to do this in REST , I am using MS FLOW as my REST API engine.

Answer (score 0):

We can use PnP PowerShell to change theme for those site collections.

[Set-PnPWebTheme](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpwebtheme?view=sharepoint-ps)

To get all site collections from the tenant, we can use the script below.

```
$cred = Get-Credential

Connect-PnPOnline "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com" -Credentials $cred
$SiteCollections = Get-PnPTenantSite
foreach ($SiteCollection in $SiteCollections)
{
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteCollection.Url -Credentials $cred

}
```

Comment: nope, Powershell not allowed in this environment, it has to be at least REST endpoint, but thanks anyway..

Comment: You can try to refer to the official document below to achieve it.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-rest-api#applytheme